# Prove that a graph doesn't contain a cycle

Tags: graph-theory

Graph $G$ has $n$ vertices of degree $4$ and $2(n+1)$ vertices of degree $1$. If $G$ is connected, prove that it doesn't have a cycle.

How can we prove that a graph doesn't have any cycles?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: How many edges does $G$ have? How many vertices? What do you know about the numbers of vertices and edges in a tree?